# Append data to url while writing into an input on latest version of Next JS

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css, react-hook-form, next.js13, radix

Basically, I have a form input that will be used to create a query param, and once it is appended to the URL that query param will be used to filter data on any service we have.
**
The project uses app routing system, Tailwind, and react-hook-form as well as Radix UI.**

---

I have tried a few things but none of them worked. I hope you'll be able to help me.

```
'use client'
import { MagnifyingGlassIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/solid'
import * as Form from '@radix-ui/react-form'

import { Flex } from '@radix-ui/themes'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import { Controller, Resolver, useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

type FormValues = {
  search: string
}

const resolver: Resolver<FormValues> = async (values) => {
  return {
    values: values.search ? values : {},
    errors: values.search
      ? {}
      : {
          search: {
            type: 'required',
            message: 'This is required.',
          },
        },
  }
}

export const Search: React.FC = () => {
  const resolverMemo = useMemo(() => resolver, [])
  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false)
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsClient(true)
  }, [])

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormValues>({ resolver: resolverMemo })

  const handleSearch = () => {
    handleSubmit((data) => {
      if (!data) return
      router.push(data.search)
    })
  }

  if (!isClient) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <Form.Root>
      <Form.Field name="search">
        <Flex width="100%">
          <MagnifyingGlassIcon className="h-8 p-2 text-white bg-zinc-800 rounded-l-sm  duration-100 hover:scale-105" />
          <Form.Control asChild>
            <Controller
              control={control}
              name="search"
              render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
                <input
                  placeholder="Search a project..."
                  type="search"
                  className="outline-none border-b border-gray-200 px-4 text-sm focus-within:ring-1 focus-within:ring-blue-400 hover:ring-1 hover:ring-blue-600 focus-within:shadow-md focus-within:shadow-slate-300 rounded-r-lg "
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Form.Control>
        </Flex>
      </Form.Field>
    </Form.Root>
  )
}
```

My goal is to append the query to the URL the param while writing on that input field without rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use router.replace() method instead of .push method, which will prevent adding new url entry.

```
router.replace(data.search)
```